# Im looking to ask for user input, but instead, my code returns me back to the beginning without giving the chance to enter input

Tags: java

so, i am looking to write code which firstly asks for user input in order to run the desired operation, this element of my code is working fine, but after selecting one of the options from the first menu i am asking the user for a second string input which i would like to turn to both lower and uppercase, but instead of letting me enter an input, the program just goes back to the original screen showing all options.

this is my code asking for a string input that isnt working:

```
else if(choice1==1)
            {
                System.out.println("================================="+"\n"+"You have chosen to convert a given string to upper case and lowercase, please enter your string: "+"\n");
                choice2 = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Your lowercase string: "+choice2.toLowerCase()+"\n"+"Your uppercase string: "+choice2.toUpperCase);
            }
```

Cheers for the help guys!!

Comment: Does is work with other options of `choice1`? Which data type has `choice1`? What says the debugger at this point?

Comment: choice1 is an int and wrks fine but choice2 with is a String does not work

Comment: I copied your snippet and it works fine... Do you see the text output?

Comment: i see the text output, but it doesnt give me a chance to provide a string input, instead it reprints my options for choice1 riht after the text output

Comment: Before this you obviously have sc.nextInt(). It doesn't consume the end of line character after the integer, so it is consumed by the next nextLine(), which gets an empty string. Add sc.nextLine() after your nextInt() to fix this.

Comment: im not sure i get how that would look, it is possible for you to show me how you would implement that in code?

Comment: like this? ```choice1 = sc.nextInt()nextLine();```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consume the end of line character:

```
choice1 = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();  // consume the end of line
// Now your program continues as before.
// Probably you have an 'if' here, I don't know, you
// haven't shown it
```